# Absolute overlay <div> doesn't cover relatively positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I'm using an absolutely positioned div to cover/mask another component and it works well except when one of those components is an element using certain display styles, like relative.  When that's the case, the element (like an image button) is not masked and can still be interacted with, which is what I'm trying to avoid.  This quick example code demonstrates the issue.  Is there an easy way to make sure the "mask" div covers everything regardless of how it's positioned?  I tried playing with Z-index but it doesn't seem to apply in this scenario.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head><title>Example</title></head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:200px; width:400px; background-color:green;">
            <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; background-color:black; opacity:0.5;"></div>
            Test<br />
            <input type="image" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" style="position:relative; top:25px;" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try setting z-index to some high value for absolute positioned mask div.

Comment: Interestingly enough, setting the Z-index on only the overlay worked for me in this example that I threw together, but not in my actual application, which is obviously going to be a little more complex. I was thinking that the difference could be related to one of the additional divs (some of which might have position attributes) wrapping the image button in the real world example.  But even then, it's only the button that is "popping through" the overlap, not any of the wrapping divs.  I'll have to investigate a little more when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser id this an issue in?
I would try using this CSS first and then compare results in IE and FF

```
div {
position:relative;
z-index:1;
height:200px;
width:400px; 
background-color:green;
}

div div {
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
background-color:black;
opacity:0.5;
}

div div input {
position:relative;
top:25px;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: This does work but is it really necessary to specify position and z-index for every element involved?  As it turns out, in this simple example, adding a z-index for only the overlay works fine (in FF at least) but it doesn't seem to work in the actual application.  Makes me wondering if the positioning on one of the wrapping divs is causing it to behave differently than the simple example.  I might just end up using jQUery BlockUI but I would like to use a simple implementation if possible, not to mention that now I'm just curious.  :)

Comment: IE's (6&7) z-index model is flawed unfortunately. If you position something, relative or absolute, with a mind to do an overlay; 99% of the time you need to specify a z-index for all elements. Additionally if you want to specify a z-index you need to position the element.     Essentially every time you specify position you start a new z-index stack. Setting the z-index of the wrapping element ensures the sub elements start at the same base index.        This is the most robust CSS only method - you could subtract from this and see what works. Also surely this is less admin than a 3rd party js?

Answer (score 1):

Look this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Briganti/A6SsR/)

Note:

- set position relative to wrapper div
- set overlay width, height size
- set z-index for elements (where you want to use **z-index**, you need to define **position**)

Answer (score 0):

There's a helpful [resource](http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/01/27/ie-bug-text-ignores-z-index-of-higher-elements/) to address this issue.

Long story short, if your absolutely placed div (.abs) is empty, IE doesn't like to place it in front of other elements regardless of z-index. You can use a 1x1 transparent gif to overcome this, eg. by adding the following style to the div:

```
   background: transparent url('/images/clear.gif') repeat 0 0;
```

I've found this to help. It's great as there's very little additional styling needed and you don't have to explicitly manage z-indices as with other answers here.

Note: You may need to move the absolutely placed div to be the last element in the parent container.

Comment: This answer (still relevant, by the way, because IE8/IE9 are still supported and negative z-indices are not recommended/do not work as a hack in IE8/IE9) is pure gold.